# Convergence/Divergence of $\int_{0}^{1/e} \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{(\log^2 (x)-1)^{3/2}} \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Initially I wanted to compute 
$$\int_{0}^{1/e} \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{(\log^2 (x)-1)^{3/2}} \mathrm{dx}$$
but it seems that Mathematica says that the integral diverges. I thought of
some variable change, but I also wonder if there is something easy to prove
it diverges. Any hint / suggestion here would be precious to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try substituting $x=e^{-u-1}$ to get
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{u+1}{(u^2+2u)^{3/2}}e^{-u-1}\mathrm{d}u
=\int_0^\infty\color{#00A000}{\frac{u+1}{(u+2)^{3/2}e}}\color{#C00000}{u^{-3/2}}\color{#0000FF}{e^{-u}}\mathrm{d}u
$$
The part in green is bounded over the positive reals. $e^{-u}$ would be integrable at $\infty$, but the factor of $u^{-3/2}$ is not integrable at $0$.

Therefore, the integral does not converge.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Making the change of variables $ x=e^{-(t+1)} $ gives

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac { \left( t+1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-t-1}}}{{
t}^{3/2} \left( t+2 \right) ^{3/2}}}{dt}. $$

The integrand behaves as $c\,t^{-3/2}$ as $t \to 0 $.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1/\expo{}}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over \bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{x} - 1}^{3/2}}
     \,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{\pars{~x \equiv \expo{-t}\quad\imp\quad t = -\ln\pars{x}~}\quad}$ and $\ds{\quad\Lambda > \expo{}}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1/\Lambda}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over \bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{x} - 1}^{3/2}}
> \,\dd x}
> =\int_{\infty}^{\ln\pars{\Lambda}}{t \over \pars{t^{2} - 1}^{3/2}}\,\pars{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{t\ =\ \ln\pars{\Lambda}}^{t\ \to\ \infty}
> \expo{-t}\dd\bracks{\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-1/2}}
> ={1 \over \Lambda\root{\ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda} - 1}}
> -\int_{\ln\pars{\Lambda}}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over \root{t^{2} - 1}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \Lambda\root{\ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda} - 1}}
> -\int_{\ln\pars{\Lambda}}^{1}{\expo{-t} \over \root{t^{2} - 1}}\,\dd t
> -\
> \underbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over \root{t^{2} - 1}}\,\dd t}
> _{\ds{=\ {\rm K}_{0}\pars{1}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm K}_{\nu}\pars{z}}$ is a
>   [Modiffied Bessel Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_374.htm).
>   [See](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm) ${\bf\mbox{9.6.23}}$.

The first term, in the right hand side, shows clearly the divergence:
$$
{1 \over \Lambda\root{\ln^{2}\pars{\Lambda} - 1}}
\sim {1 \over \root{2\expo{}}}\,{1 \over \pars{\Lambda - \expo{}}^{1/2}}\,,
\qquad \Lambda \gtrsim \expo{}
$$