# Prove that $\int_0^{1/e} \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}=K_{0}(1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Prove that
$$\int_0^{1/e} \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}=K_{0}(1)$$
where $K_{n}(x)$ is the modified bessel function of the second kind.
Some hints/suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing variables to $u=\ln x$, and then going by parts?

Comment: @LevLivnev: I thought of $x=e^u$. I'll go that way right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t = \ln(x)$. Then the integral becomes:
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} \mathrm{e}^{t} \mathrm{d} t \stackrel{u=-t}{=} \int_{1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-u)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} \mathrm{d} u 
$$
Now compare this to eq. [10.3.28](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265499/prove-that-int-01-e-frac-mathrmdx-sqrt-ln-x2-1-k-01#265505) of the DLMF handbook of special functions.
$$
  \int_{1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-u)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} \mathrm{d} u  = \left.\frac{\Gamma\left(\nu+1/2\right)}{ \sqrt{\pi} \left(z/2\right)^{\nu}} K_\nu(z) \right|_{\nu=0, z=1} = K_0(1)
$$

Comment: just brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265450/convergence-divergence-of-int-01-e-frac-log-left-frac1x-right/265467#265467). Use the change of variable $x=e^{-(t+1)}$ and you will find that the new integrand behaves like $c\,t^{-1/2}$ as $t\to 0$.

**Edit:** 
Now, to evaluate the integral, we use the change of variables $x=e^{-(t+1)}$

$$ \int_0^{1/e} \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}=\frac{1}{e}\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-t}}}{\sqrt {t}\sqrt {t+2}}
}{dt} . $$

We will consider the more general integral

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{\sqrt {t}\sqrt {t+2}}
}{dt}. $$

The above integral is nothing but the Laplace transform of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+2t}}$ which is given by

$$e^sK_0(s).$$

So, we have

$$ \frac{1}{e}\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-t}}}{\sqrt {t}\sqrt {t+2}}
}{dt}=\frac{1}{e}\lim_{s\to 1} e^sK_{0}(s)=K_{0}(1). $$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. Does it prove that $\int_0^{1/e} \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\sqrt{(\ln x)^2-1}}=K_{0}(1)$?

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the OP's question at all.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: I added more materials.