# test for convergence of improper integral1

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 {x^n\log x\over(1+x)^2} \, dx$$

I tried something using practical test, but not much progress.

I see that the integral becomes improper for $x=0$, May be we need to apply the Practical comparison test ?
I need some hint please.

Comment: You just asked a very similar question; could you give some indication in your question about what you think the potential barriers to integrability are, or some details about the tests you tried?

Comment: @EricTressler unfortunately they are not similar :(.  but i will update the question with whatever i understand :)

Comment: Hint: Near 0 we have $\frac{x^n \log x}{(1+x)^2} \sim x^n \log x$ (in the sense that their ratio tends to 1, as $x \to 0$)

Comment: How is this an improper integral?  As $x\to0$, the value of the function approaches $0$, so there's no vertical asymptote and no need to take a limit as the lower bound of integration approaches $0$.  The function is in fact bounded on the interval over which one integrates, and that interval is bounded.

Comment: This is not an improper integral.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to see that the integral
$$\int_0^1|\log x|\, dx$$
is convergent so conclude with the inequalities
$$\frac{x^n|\log x|}{(1+x)^2}\leq |\log x|,\quad 0<x\leq1, \, n\geq0$$

and
$$-\frac{x^n\log x}{(1+x)^2}\sim_0-x^n\log x\geq\frac{1}{x^{-n}}\quad 0<x\leq\frac{1}{e}, \, n<0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\lim_{x\to 0+} x^n\ln x=0,\quad n> 0$$ and $$\left|\int_0^1\ln x\,dx\right|<\infty.$$

Comment: In fact, $n> -1$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal What do you mean? If the first limit, then it's true only for $n>0$. If you mean the author's question, then there're no indications for the possible values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265450/convergence-divergence-of-int-01-e-frac-log-left-frac1x-right/265467#265467). Note that,

$$ x\sim 0  \implies \frac{x^n\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)}\sim x^n\ln(x).$$

Now, the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln(x) dx = \frac{x^{n+1}\ln(x)}{n+1}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1} x^{n+1}dx=-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1} x^{n+1}dx. $$

Now, do you know for what $n$ the last integral converge?

Comment: if $n$ is  negative then $\frac{x^{n+1}\ln(x)}{n+1}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=1}$ isn't zero.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: How about $n>-1$?

Comment: Yes you work is valid  if $n>-1$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I just want the OP to do some work.

Answer (score 0):

This is in no sense an improper integral.

$$
x\log x = \frac{\log x}{1/x},
$$
and by L'Hopital's rule this goes to $0$ as $x\downarrow0$.  Therefore $x^n\log x\to0$ as $x\downarrow0$.  The denominator stays far from $0$ over the whole interval.

So the function is bounded, and it's integrated over a bounded interval, so there is no "impropriety".  No test for convergence is needed.